# C functions and access to Objective-C instance variables

Tags: objective-c, c, instance-variables

I have an a property declared in `.h` as

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int timeSig_Numerator;
```

and an instance variable declared in the `.h` as

```
int mTimeSig_Numerator;
```

in the `.m` I synthesize with

```
@synthesize timeSig_Numerator = mTimeSig_Numerator;
```

I have a C function declared before the synthesize and need to use mTimeSig_Numerator. what is the best way to make the instance variable visible to my C function without passing it in as a function argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `mTimeSig_Numerator` is an instance variable, each instance of your class has its own `mTimeSig_Numerator`. As a C function is decoupled from any given class/class instance, how would it know from which instance it should obtain `mTimeSig_Numerator`?

Your C function needs either an argument containing the value of `mTimeSig_Numerator` in a specific instance, or an argument pointing to the instance itself, or some other mechanism that tells the function which specific instance/instance variable it should use.

Comment: I see, I hadn't thought about the C function not being 'part' of the class. Thank you.